# Creating an automatic schedule for workers using Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program that takes a list of workers and slots to be filled to come up with a schedule convenient for each worker and filling all the slots. Each worker has a maximum amount of shifts (note that the worker doesn't have to work consecutive shifts), and a list of slots for which they will be available to fill. The program returns `False` if all slots are not filled, or else it produces a list of workers assigned to the various slots.

A mock example of the data set and expected result:

I tried starting off by creating a class for workers initialized by (name, max_shifts, avail_slots) and then some getter methods.

```
Udon = ('Udon', 1, [3,4])
Ramen = ('Ramen', 1, [2])
Soba = ('Soba' , 2, [1,3])

Noodle-workers = [Soba, Ramen, Udon]
Slots = [1, 2, 3, 4]

Schedule(Noodle-workers, Slots)
```

and this is expected to return:

> Udon - 4
>   Soba - 3
>   Ramen - 2
>   Soba - 1

They could be all in a list or a dictionary and each line could be a tuple. There is creative leverage on how the result appears. But the function returns `False` if a slot is not filled

Another data set to test the scalability of the program is as follows:

```
Erika  = Worker("Erika",   1, [1, 3, 7, 9])
Ryan   = Worker("Ryan",    1,   [1, 8, 10])
Reece  = Worker("Reece",   1,       [5, 6])
Gordon = Worker("Gordon",  2,    [2, 3, 9])
David  = Worker("David",   2,    [2, 8, 9])
Katie  = Worker("Katie",   1,       [4, 6])
Aashish= Worker("Aashish", 2,      [1, 10])
Grant  = Worker("Grant",   2,      [1, 11])
Raeanne= Worker("Raeanne", 2,  [1, 11, 12])
Erin   = Worker("Erin",    1,          [4])
Alex   = Worker("Alex",    1,          [7])

Workers = [Erika, Ryan, Reece, Gordon, David, Katie, Aashish, Grant, 
Raeanne, Erin] 
SLOTS = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

switch Erin (Workers[9]) with Alex in the workers list to get a full Schedule for all slots

My main problem is breaking down the concept to approach the problem. I thought of a tree-like structure to produce all possible combinations of assignments for workers and then eliminating those that don't satisfy the max-shifts. This was also problematic for me in a situation of choosing between two workers eligible for a slot. Furthermore I had the sense that generative recursion would probably solve the problem, but I'm at a loss on how to implement it with the accompanying structures to produce the result.

Anyway I'll really appreciate it if this problem can be solved and also the concept of solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a tree where nodes are the assignment problems themselves (a 'list of workers'/'list of slots' pair) and edges are individual assignments ("put Udon on slot 3").

Here, a worker is not just a named person, it is a person together with the relevant work information: remaining shifts, available slots.

This is how it would start:

[image: noodle tree]

A depth-first search is then doable:

```
class Worker:

    def __init__(self, name, shifts, slots):
        self.name = name
        self.shifts = shifts
        self.slots = slots

    def copy(self):
        return Worker(self.name, self.shifts, self.slots[:])

    def assign(self, slot):
        assert slot in self.slots
        self.shifts -= 1
        self.slots.remove(slot)

def Schedule(team, slots):
    if slots == []:
        return {}
    for worker in team:
        if worker.shifts > 0:
            for slot in worker.slots:
                if slot in slots:
                    wcp = worker.copy()
                    new_team = [w if w != worker else wcp for w in team]
                    wcp.assign(slot)
                    assignments = Schedule(new_team, [s for s in slots if s != slot])
                    if assignments is not None:
                        assignments[slot] = worker.name
                        return assignments
    return None

Udon = Worker('Udon', 1, [3,4])
Ramen = Worker('Ramen', 1, [2])
Soba = Worker('Soba' , 2, [1,3])            

Noodle_workers = [Soba, Ramen, Udon]
Slots = [1, 2, 3, 4]

print(Schedule(Noodle_workers, Slots))
```

**Update**. A few explanations:

- list comprehensions: I use them and (probably) abuse them, they make creating lists so much faster. Notice that the `if` keyword is in different positions because each line uses a different mechanism:

  - `[w if w != worker else wcp for w in team]`: simple list comprehension (`[expr(i) for i in ...]`) combined with a ternary operator (`a if b else c`)
  - `[s for s in slots if s != slot]`: conditional list comprehension (`[expr(i) for i in ... if <condition>]`.
- Expanding: the proposed implementation uses recursion, the depth of which will be equal to the number of slots to be assigned. If that number is high, this could be a problem.
- Purpose of `new_team`: before going into that, I'll start by explaining the tree-model a little more in detail.

  - The starting problem is defined by giving a pool of workers and a list of slots they need to be assigned to.
  - Each worker is **characterized** by its name, the number of shifts he can make, the list of slots he is available for.
  - When a worker is assigned to a slot, we have to update the number of shifts he still can work, and the list of slots he remains available for. This happens in the `assign` method:

    ```
    self.shifts -= 1
    self.slots.remove(slot)
    ```

    We also remove the chosen slot from the list of slots to assign.
  - This then leads to a new assignment problem: how to assign the remaining workers to the remaining slots? Every choice for the first worker leads to a different new assignment problem. The new assignment problem is a child node of the previous problem in our tree structure.
  - During the depth-first search, if one search is unsuccessful, we will have to step back up in the tree continue to loop over possible assignments in the parent node.

Now note that a problem consists of a list of `Worker` objects (or lists in the OP's code) and a list of slots. In python, lists and objects are passed by reference (pointer). If, in a given step of our depth-first search, a `Worker` object is modified (as it is bound to be once that worker has been assigned), this object stays modified when we climb back up the tree to explore other branches, which would break the code. To avoid that, we create a copy of every worker that is to be assigned:

```
                wcp = worker.copy()
```

and pass this copy to the child-nodes after modification. Doing so we guarantee that no data will be corrupted when we come back to that node.

The same problem would arise for the list of slots: if we passed `slots` to the child nodes, after removing a slot using `slots.remove(slot)`, and if some of the child nodes did the same, the list `slots` would end up broken, as would the list `team` if we did the same.

This is solved by passing a new list of workers ans a new list of slots to the child nodes.

Comment: Thanks @ChristophFrings. I'm still relatively new to coding on python and I observed something new in your code, i.e. the list-comprehension: new_team = [w if w != worker else wcp for w in team] & [s for s in slots if s != slot]. I've looked it up and I'm getting to understand it, so thanks a lot for adding to my learning. Concerning the code it seems it works great for the above test condition but it doesn't scale well with more workers. I'll post another test condition so you'll see what I'm trying to say. In the meantime I'll be musing over the diagram you posted, it is really insightful.

Comment: Please if you don't mind me asking what was your goal for the new_team variable because I put in a print statement after it and each time it goes through the loop it returns the same list and causes the recursive call on assignment become an infinite loop. so I figured that I just use team in the recursive call and it at least produced a result even though the maximum availability of some workers were exceeded

Comment: @Daniel1234 The program works fine for the second example you posted (without Alex). But it takes a very long time. If you put the slot 7 first in Erika's list of slots, it takes less than a second.

Comment: thanks again, I'm very much appreciative of the time you have given to this and the insight you have shared. I understand more of what your code is doing and I'll be studying your code closely to come up with my variant so hopefully I'll share it to get your thoughts. Once again thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @ChristophFrings I'm really excited to show you what I've done. As promised I studied your code and in the process of testing and debugging, I observed that it was very much important to sort the workers in the team according to the length of the list of slots(i.e. Worker.slots, I however use getters so Worker.get_slots()). The reason sorting is very important is that like in the case of Erika with many possible slots, once she is assigned to a slot she would not be able to fill a critical slot down the line. So filling those with fewer options is better first off and then those more flexible can fill in the remaining slots. It may just be my system (2GB RAM, intel duo core), but running your initially code without the sort felt like an infinite loop especially when I put in print statements to better understand your work.

Also I observed that the False condition (i.e. when a schedule absolutely cannot be attained) went into an infinite loop in your initial code. Maybe it worked on your system but I tried it after your last post and 30mins to an hour the code was still running, so I tried to tweak it to ensure that when the False condition is met the code ends. I did this by adding one more base condition and a break condition.

I can't thank you enough because I think I have learnt so much from your code. The concept of the code below is inspired by your work in many ways. The main differences are adding to the base case, adopting a sort function I recently learnt for an online course on edx, and lastly employing the use of a dictionary showing all workers suitable for a given slot. This meant that the code did not have to mechanically follow everyone in the order of the list and then fill each person to the maximum shifts before moving to the next worker. This I also observed in your initial code and I felt it was more important to follow down the list of slots than down the workers.

Well Here is the modified code.

```
class Worker(object):
    def __init__ (self, name, shifts, slots):
        self.name  = name
        self.shifts = shifts
        self.slots = slots  # Slot is a list of available slots a TA can fill

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_shifts(self):
        return self.shifts

    def get_slots(self):
        return self.slots

    def copy(self):
        return Worker(self.name, self.shifts, self.slots[:])

    def assign(self, slot):
        assert slot in self.slots
        self.slots.remove(slot)
        self.shifts -= 1

    def __str__ (self):
        return  self.name + ', max-shifts = ' + str(self.shifts) + ', slots = ' + '[' + ','.join(str(e) for e in self.slots) +']' 

def merge(left, right):
    ''' Helper function for the merge_sort function that follows'''
    result = []
    i,j = 0,0

    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
        # This is the criterion merge_sort uses to sort the list argument
        # in this case I'll be sorting according to the length of list of slots for each Worker
        if len(left[i].get_slots()) < len(right[j].get_slots()): 
            result.append(left[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            result.append(right[j])
            j += 1

    while i < len(left):
        result.append(left[i])
        i += 1
    while j < len(right):
        result.append(right[j])
        j += 1

    return result

def merge_sort(L):
    ''' This sorts any List according to the condition in the func above'''
    if len(L) < 2:
        return L[:]
    else:
        middle = len(L)//2
        left  = merge_sort(L[:middle])
        right = merge_sort(L[middle:])
        return merge(left, right)

def poss_assignments(team, slots):
    """
    creates a list of possible assignments for every available slot

    team - List of Workers
    slots - List of positive integer (slots)

    return - Dictionary with slots as keys and a list of Workers as values
    """
    poss_dict = {}
    poss_slots = slots[:]


    for i in poss_slots:
        val_list = []
        poss_dict[i] = val_list
        for t in team:
            if i in t.get_slots():
                poss_dict[i] += [t]  #replace with [t.get_name()]: Use this to see the names this func produces 

    return poss_dict

def Schedule(team, slots):
    team = merge_sort(team)
    if slots == []:
        return {}
    elif team == [] and slots != []:
        return print('No Workers to assign')

    possible_assignments = poss_assignments(team,slots) # A dictionary of slots with list of workers open for that slot

    accu_slot = slots[:]

    i = 0

    for slot in accu_slot:
       if slot in possible_assignments.keys():
           while i < len(possible_assignments[slot]):
               worker = possible_assignments[slot][i]
               wcp = worker.copy()
               wcp.assign(slot)

               new_slots = [s for s in slots if s != slot]
               new_team = [w if w != worker else wcp for w in team]

               assignment = Schedule(new_team, new_slots)

               if assignment is not 'Schedule unattainable.':
                   assignment[slot] = wcp.get_name()
                   return assignment
               else:
                   i += 1

       else:

           break

    return 'Schedule unattainable.'

#Udon = Worker('Udon', 1, [3,4])
#Ramen = Worker('Ramen', 1, [2])
#Soba = Worker('Soba' , 2, [1,3])            
#
#Noodle_workers = [Soba, Ramen, Udon]
#Slots = [1, 2, 3, 4]

#==============================================================================
Erika  = Worker("Erika",   1, [1, 3, 7, 9])
Ryan   = Worker("Ryan",    1,   [1, 8, 10])
Reece  = Worker("Reece",   2,       [5, 6])
Gordon = Worker("Gordon",  2,    [2, 3, 9])
David  = Worker("David",   2,    [2, 8, 9])
Katie  = Worker("Katie",   1,       [4, 6])
Aashish= Worker("Aashish", 2,      [1, 10])
Grant  = Worker("Grant",   2,      [1, 11])
Raeanne= Worker("Raeanne", 2,  [1, 11, 12])
Erin   = Worker("Erin",    1,          [4])
Alex   = Worker("Alex",    1,          [7])

Workers = [Erika, David, Grant, Raeanne, Ryan, Reece, Gordon, Katie, Aashish]
Slots = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

#print(Schedule(Workers, Slots))
#print(Schedule(Noodle_workers, Slots))
```

Pardon me if the code doesn't appear properly I'm still trying to get a hang on posting code on this forum with the indentation requirements.

Any way once again thanks a lot, and please do me a favor and test the code with various conditions like empty workers list with slots having elements and vice versa, slots with a number that has no worker available to fill (i.e. a key in the possible_assignments with no worker in the list, etc. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I am sorry but I tried the code for same data you have in it but with all workers available for all 12 shifts. and it does not produce a proper answer. It gives all shifts to the first worker. Maybe I am doing it wrong!